# Grafana Panel JSON to Jsonnet?

Tags: grafana, jsonnet

I'm able to generate Panel JSON for provisioning a Grafana dashboard like so:

```
jsonnet -J ~/grafana/grafonnet-lib mydash.jsonnet > mydash.json
```

However I like to manipulate and edit the resulting dashboard in Grafana itself.

What I am absolutely puzzled and frustrated by, is once I've made the UI changes in Grafana by tweaking its settings and such... how does one get that **back** into Jsonnet? Right now for me it's a super awkward development experience. I export the Panel JSON and open the source Jsonnet in a seperate window and earnestly try port my changes across.

This is especially painful when in the JSON you might have:

```
      "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": true,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": true
      },
```

That you would need to manually translate to Jsonnet/Graffonet-lib:

```
sparklineShow=true,
sparklineFull=true,
colorBackground=true,
```

Am I missing a trick or work flow?

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit mydash.jsonnet and add the needed properties there. There is currently no automated way that I know to translate back from grafana-json to grafonnet. It is a bit of a pain to find the right properties sometimes.

The properties you are looking for are here: https://github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib/blob/master/grafonnet/singlestat.libsonnet#L44

Something like this should work:

```
local grafana = import 'grafonnet/grafana.libsonnet';


grafana.dashboard.new(
  'Sparkline Example'
)
.addPanel(
  grafana.singlestat.new(
    'uptime',
    format='s',
    span=4,
    valueName='current',
    sparklineFillColor='rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)',
    sparklineFull=true,
    sparklineLineColor='rgb(31, 120, 193)',
    sparklineShow=true,
  )
  .addTarget(
    grafana.prometheus.target(
      'time()',
    )
  ), gridPos={
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 24,
    h: 3,
  }
)
```